# Getting velocity.js working on JSBin

Tags: javascript, jsbin, velocity.js

This has got to be simple; what am I doing wrong?

http://jsbin.com/tayemi/2/

Velocity doesn't seem to want to do anything.

Comment: Did you not notice all those red errors at the bottom of your JavaScript tab?

Comment: They were inconsistent — so I wasn't sure what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you have to change this:

```
 $("p").velocity( { width: 50px }, 1000);
```

on this:

```
 $("p").velocity( { width: "50px" }, 1000);
```

2) you are using resources from github. but these resources are loaded not as *.js files but as plain text (with MIME type  text/plain instead of text/javascript). So, you have to change this.
Here is my example on JSBin http://jsbin.com/fatihopipe/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You've got to put quotes around the width value or else you've got syntax errors, so nothing will happen. You also need to make sure your code waits for the DOM to be built:

```
$(function() {
  $("p").velocity( { width: "50px" }, 1000);
});
```